# How should i localize email templates in laravel?

Tags: email, laravel, localization, laravel-blade

I have following files structure now for email templates: `~/resources/views/emails/$template.blade.php`

I would like to implement following structure with fallback to default locale: 
`~/resources/views/emails/$locale/$template.blade.php`

It is very common issue, but unfortunately i can't find ready solutions. What is best way to implement this? Or perhaps there are some existing solutions you could advise?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see any problem here. You can check if your localized email exists with `View::exists('emails/'. $locale .'/'. $template)` and if it doesn't exist load the `$fallback_locale` one.